# Objective-C Switch Statements for images

Tags: objective-c, image, switch-statement

I am trying to have my iOS app pull images instead of changing the background color.

```
 CCColor *backgroundColor = nil;
    switch (self.value) {
        case 2:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:20.f/255.f blue:80.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 4:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:20.f/255.f blue:140.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 8:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:60.f/255.f blue:220.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 16:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:120.f/255.f blue:120.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 32:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:160.f/255.f blue:120.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 64:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:20.f/255.f green:160.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 128:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:50.f/255.f green:160.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 256:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:80.f/255.f green:120.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 512:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:140.f/255.f green:70.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 1024:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:170.f/255.f green:30.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f];
            break;
        case 2048:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:220.f/255.f green:30.f/255.f blue:30.f/255.f];
            break;
        default:
            backgroundColor = [CCColor greenColor];
            break;
    }
    _backgroundNode.color = backgroundColor;
```

This is the code. What would be the difference? How do I make it change for each case to pull a different image instead of changing the background color. This is a 2048 Game I am playing with to help teach me and I am trying to put pictures instead of the numbers.

Comment: Consider putting the images or the image names in an `NSDictionary` with the `NSNumber` of the value for the key and then just indexing by the `NSNumber` of the value. Even in the current case such a dictionary could be used for the color values.

Comment: If you name the images appropriately you can create the names as needed with `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
backgroundColor = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"Name of Image"];
```

Just use that for every case and change the file name accordingly.

Comment: Begs the question of the how the image name is obtained.

Comment: I don't get it... honestly I don't understand jokes very well lol

Comment: There is no joke. The answer does not answer the question of how to get the correct image name.

Comment: Well, the asker should make multiple images for each block such as 2,4,8,16 and set them accordingly.

Comment: I would use backgroundColor = [CCSprite spriteWithImageName:@"Name of Image"]; but I don't think I put my images in my sprite builder correctly. Do I only have to put them in the Xcode project or do they need to be in the sprite builder as well? I just want to take these images and make them the tiles instead of the numbers in 2048. Maybe I am doing it all wrong.

Comment: Also when I try to method you suggested, when I run, it causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Name the images after the value: image2, image4, image8, etc. Use whatever base name you choose.

Then create the name on-the-fly:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", self.value];
```

Then load the image, the image must be directly in the app directory (main bundle file):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

If the images are in another location such as a directory in the bundle use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Im sorry, I am very new at objective-c but I really don't understand what your talking about here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

it wouldn't be so different something along the lines:

```
NSString * imageName = @"";

    switch (self.value) {
        case 2:
            imageName = @"imagefor2";
            break;
        case 4:
            imageName = @"imagefor4";
            break;
        case 8:
            imageName = @"imagefor8";
            break;
        case 1024:
           imageName = @"imagefor1024";
            break;
        case 2048:
            imageName = @"imagefor2048";
            break;
        default:
            imageName = @"image";
            break;
    }
//the image
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
// _backgroundNode.imageView
```